# Xamarin Targetframeworkversion

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to make a basic Xamarin.forms (pcl) application (in Visual studio 2017) and i want to Target Lolipop (5.0.0, api level 21).

So i made a basic Xamarin solution and i adjusted the Android properties all to Android 5.0 lollipop

- Compile using Android version "Android 5.0 (Lollipop)"
- Minimum  Android to target "Android 5.0 (API Level 21 - Lollipop)"
- Target    Android Version "Android 5.0 (API Level 21 - Lollipop)"

Unfortunately in my warning list i get the following

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning     The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (v7.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v5.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project. Prolang.Android C:\Projects\Prolang\Prolang\Prolang.Android\Prolang.Android.csproj

If i google for this error most people say to indeed update your android project to use the latest Targetframework version. But in my case i really want to only be able to call Api calls that are available to level 21 aka Android 5.0 Lollipop. As in i want the compile time safety net that i only use Api Calls from Api level 21.

To me it seems like i have to downgrade my xamarin.Forms dll to a version that is made specifically for android lollipop since the one i use right now targets a higher version.

So should i downgrade my xamarin.forms dll to achieve this and get rid of the error? And if i downgrade to what version do i need to downgrade so i target Android 5.0 Lollipop? This information is all pretty unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xamarin.Forms` is designed using the Android's support libraries so it will run on a wide range of APIs without any additional actions from the developer.

If you are using native APIs via `Xamarin.Android` (assumably via Forms' Dependency Service) then yes you would have to be aware of the API level  of the method calls.

That said, since `Xamarin.Forms` uses the `com.android.support.*` libraries and you would have to have to a Forms versions that uses `com.android.support:design:21.x.x` and the associated Android build tools for API 21.

Now you can review the package dependancies and you will see that your choices are Forms' is `1.4`

```
`1.4.0.6336-pre1` to `1.4.4.6449`
```

Note: `v1.5.x` moved to version 22 of the Android support libraries

**IMHO** using Forms's `1.4` would a bad mistake due to its age and the mountain of improvements and bugs fixes since 2015, you are so much better off:

- Using the latest Forms version
- Set the `Framework version` to latest (7.1)
- Set the `Target Android version` to `Android 5.0 (API Level 21)`
- Set the `Minimum Android version` to whatever you need...
- Forgo the compile time API checks
- Check runtime API issues via API-21 devices and emulators

Comment: Thanks for the answer already, so this means that i cannot have Compile time safety but i should implement my own safetynet at runtime?

"For go the compile time API checks" because i have problems understanding this bullet

Comment: @Martijn `For go`, typo, should be forgo (i.e. go without). What type of runtime "safety net" are you looking for? i.e. If you use an API22 class/method by mistake and run in on a API21 device it will fail, that is what emulator and device testing is all about.

Comment: @Martijn And remember you would be setting the `android:targetSdkVersion` in the app's manifest to 21 in this case and thus your app still runs like a API21 built app when run on APIs 22-26..

Comment: Ok, yes it will fail at runtime then not at compile time. Something i was trying to avoid in the first place. I will do it the way you said and set the settings like you told me.

Comment: @Martijn FYI, I've done a few projects where they use custom Android hardware and are locked to an older API (lots of integrated barcoding devices use only API 19) and in those cases do what I described above and thus the `Target Android version` (android:targetSdkVersion) is set to 19 and only do platform debugging and testing on API 19 devices/emulators. You will instantly find out if you used a *newer* API like `ApplicationContext.DataDir` instead of `ApplicationContext.ApplicationInfo.DataDir` due to the "XXXX method does not exist" exception ;-)